# Explain DependencyObject GetValue method

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-properties

I am trying to understand value resolution method of Dependency Property.
when I look into GetValue method of DependencyObject, I see it is calling

```
return GetValueEntry(
                    LookupEntry(dp.GlobalIndex),
                    dp,
                    null,
                    RequestFlags.FullyResolved).Value;
```

Please refer to https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#windowsbase/Base/System/Windows/DependencyObject.cs,f4481c3e6cb032a5

Inside GetValueEntry method I found following block of code -

```
if (entryIndex.Found)
{
    if ((requests & RequestFlags.RawEntry) != 0)
    {
        entry = _effectiveValues[entryIndex.Index];
    }
    else
    {
        entry = GetEffectiveValue(
                    entryIndex,
                    dp,
                    requests);
    }
}
```

Please refer to 
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#windowsbase/Base/System/Windows/DependencyObject.cs,f4481c3e6cb032a5

As per my understanding, this block of code is getting executed when the corresponding DependencyObject has an entry for the Dependency Property in EffectiveValues array, then this block of code is getting executed.

Now following is the definition

```
internal enum RequestFlags
{
    FullyResolved = 0x00,
    AnimationBaseValue = 0x01,
    CoercionBaseValue = 0x02,
    DeferredReferences = 0x04,
    SkipDefault = 0x08,
    RawEntry = 0x10,
}
```

so (requests & RequestFlags.RawEntry) would always be 0 as we are passing  RequestFlags.FullyResolved from GetValue. So that means, always GetEffectiveValue
get called.

Am I missing something? when do we get the value from _effectiveValues[entryIndex.Index]?

Also, I can see the following line of code

```
else if (!dp.IsDefaultValueChanged)
{
    return EffectiveValueEntry.CreateDefaultValueEntry(dp, dp.DefaultMetadata.DefaultValue);
}
```

How can we change the default value of an existing Dependency Property?
And why this is being checked within Get operation?

Comment: Not sure why you're doing these investigations, but if you just want to change the default value of a dependency property in a class derived from the one that declares the property, use OverrideMetadata.

Comment: Yes, in case of `GetValue` the `(requests & RequestFlags.RawEntry) != 0` condition will never be true, but the `GetValueEntry` is called from various places with different flags, e.g. [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#windowsbase/Base/System/Windows/DependencyObject.cs,727) or [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#windowsbase/Base/System/Windows/DependencyObject.cs,3081).